# Time Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, time, count, format

I want to happen something like this, when i dump a data example "05:00-05:30" to cell A1, it will add space automatic to cell B1 like this "05:00 - 05:30". Below is my formula BUT, when I input "5:00-05:30" it will have an error because 5:00 won't count as same as 05:00. My only problem here is to add spaces hh:mm - hh:mm

Input: 09:00-05:00

Result: 09:00 - 05:00

Formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,5)&" - "&RIGHT(A1,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing your "-" with " - " using the [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) function.

### Code

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-"," - ")
```

### Substitute function

> Substitutes new_text for old_text in a text string. Use SUBSTITUTE
>   when you want to replace specific text in a text string; use REPLACE
>   when you want to replace any text that occurs in a specific location
>   in a text string.

[read more](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332)

Answer (score 0):

Substitute is the easiest way for your issue here, for future reference, you can always make the [num_char] dynamic as you have a defined anchor with "-"

So building up on your formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH("-",A1)-1)&" - "&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("-",A1))
```